# Does the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 support bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, intel-centrino

Just got a Lenovo x230 to replace my x200s, and I was wondering if the Intel Centrino **Advanced**-N 6205 chipset supports bluetooth? I can find no indicators that it does in the Control Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

Intel, incapable of advertising any of their products honestly, did not incorporate bluetooth into their *advanced* 6235 chipset. Interesting, it's in the [Advanced-N 6235](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-advanced-n-6235.html), and it's the [non-advanced 2230](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-wireless-n-2230.html), and even in the [god damn 135](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-wireless-n-135.html).

As if numbers aren't decieving, the new [Ultimate lineup](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-ultimate-n-6300.html) also lacks Bluetooth.