# How to enable Bluetooth on Intel Centrino 2230 under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

In an effort to equip my Windows 7 desktop PC with a non-USB Bluetooth solution, I purchased a mini PCI-E to PCI-Express adaptor and an Intel Centrino 2230 Wireless+Bluetooth card.

The card is installed in the adaptor successfully and Windows has correctly identified and installed the device in Device Manager as "Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230" (under the Network Adapters section). However, it has not identified or installed the Bluetooth part of the card and therefore I cannot use the Bluetooth functionality.

There are no unidentified devices in Device Manager, and no devices listed under the "Bluetooth Radios" section.

I have installed the latest [Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software for Bluetooth® technology for Windows 7* 64-bit](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/66889/Intel-Centrino-Wireless-N-2230) software/drivers but this did not detect or enable any Bluetooth functionality. The software installed OK but did not add anything new (eg no Bluetooth icon).

For reference the model of the card is [Intel Centrino 2230BNHMW](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-wireless-n-2230.html).

Does anyone know how I can enable the card's Bluetooth functionality?

Comment: These cards don't actually have Bluetooth capability. They are required to make the Bluetooth module work, but don't actually have the Bluetooth technology on them: they control the Bluetooth module.

Comment: Thanks. Can one buy a Bluetooth module? Just trying to eliminate unreliable USB Bluetooth (have tried multiple dongles but always get mouse disconnections...)

Comment: No. That's not going to work. What computer do you have?

Comment: It's custom-built and it's an Intel DH67BL motherboard with Intel i7-3770 CPU .

Comment: Should've built it with Bluetooth. (JK) I think you just need to get a better Bluetooth dongle.

Comment: @Zacharee1 [This](http://superuser.com/questions/563739/does-the-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6205-support-bluetooth?rq=1) seems to disagree with you.  I suspect something else is going on.  Pictures on Amazon clearly picture the BT module.

Comment: @Ramhound How so? I said the thing doesn't have Bluetooth.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Read the answer "and it's the non-advanced 2230, and" the author indicates the card the author purchase DOES have the BT module.  Besides pictures of the card [clearly picture](http://www.amazon.com/Intel-Centrino-Express-Bluetooth-2230BNHMW/dp/B009DAFJRM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1431444569&sr=8-1&keywords=Intel+Centrino+2230BNHMW) the module is installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm. OK. I'm still going to say that it won't work, though, since just having the Bluetooth module won't work: it needs the correct chipset and computer(s).

Comment: @Zacharee1 - What chipset is the corect chipset then?  The card should work.  The card is just a PCI-e device, if given the correct drivers, both the 802.11 and BT module should work.

Comment: @Chris - Are you able to use the wireless module itself?  Have you physically confirmed it has both modules?

Comment: I see there are two similarly named software packages.  The first is Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software Bluetooth the second is Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software connection utility you installed both?

Comment: Wi-Fi is working well on the card - i'm able to connect to wireless networks etc. But the PC sees no Bluetooth adapter etc. The label on the card says 2230BNHMW which, according to the Intel site, is an 802.11 and Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: I've installed all the Win7 64bit software including the Bluetooth version - this installs but does not appear to do anything - doesn't add any new Bluetooth devices, no Bluetooth icon, etc. The installation completes but doesn't offer anything new other than a bunch of *.dll and *.exe files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Bluetooth. Also from services.msc all the Bluetooth services are started properly.

Comment: @Chris, were you able to enable Bluetooth on this card?

Comment: No, couldn't get it to work at all.